# Check if any element of a numpy array is not in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a small list:

```
moveless = [0,11,30,31,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29]
```

And, for example, an array like so (it will always come nested in a list like this, but there will often be tens/hundreds of thousands of them, and any number from -1 to 31 can be in any spot):

```
starting_board = [([[ 6, -1, -1,  11, 0,  11, -1,  -1,  -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  11, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, 20, 31, -1, 25, -1, -1, -1]])]
```

And I need to determine if any of the elements of this array are not in moveless. So if it parsed it and got to 6, it could stop.

I feel like there must be a faster and more elegant/pythonic way to do this than just a couple for loops, but my checking through the numpy docs/elsewhere on this site hasn't revealed anything terribly useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to know is if *any* of the elements are not in the list, just do a set comparison:

```
any_items_not_in_moveless = {element for row in starting_board[0] for element in row} - set(moveless)
# OR
any_items_not_in_moveless = set(np.asarray(starting_board[0]).ravel()) - set(moveless)
```

As @Chirag points out, you could also leverage Numpy's `isin` function. Which solution is faster/better for you is something you'd need to figure out for your own case:

```
any_items_not_in_moveless = (~np.asarray(starting_board[0]).isin(moveless)).any()
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [isin()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html)

```
starting_board = [([[ 6, -1, -1,  11, 0,  11, -1,  -1,  -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  11, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1, 20, 31, -1, 25, -1, -1, -1]])]
moveless = [0,11,30,31,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29]
print(np.isin(starting_board, moveless))
```

Output:

```
[[[False False False  True  True  True False False False False]
  [False False False False False False False  True False False]
  [False False False False False False False False False False]
  [False False False False False False False False False False]
  [False False False False False False False False False False]
  [False False False False False False False False False False]
  [False False False False False False False False False False]
  [False False False  True  True False  True False False False]]]
```